# Logical Implication 4

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I got stuck while reading the Discrete Mathematics book of Grimaldi. Say there are two primitives.

> p: I read physics.
>   q: I pass physics.

Now consider below lines.

(p $\to$ q) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($\neg$p $\lor$ q) which can be read as *"I don't read or I pass"*

Now read this *"I don't pass or I read"*. which can be written as (p $\lor$ $\neg$q). Both mean the same right? (Or only I perceived it like that?) then
(p $\to$ q) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($\neg$p $\lor$ q) $\Leftrightarrow$ (p $\lor$ $\neg$q)

But I know both are not equivalent because I have written truth table for it. But can you convince me using English language sentence (not truth tables) the above non equivalence.

Comment: For instance: if in the second one you "read and don't pass", then this is different from if you "don't read and pass", as a possibility in the first one.

Comment: Why do you think they are the same?  "I don't pass or I read" means you can both fail and read, but you can't pass and not read.  "I don't read or I pass" means you can pass and not read, but you can not both fail  and read.  They are complete opposites.

Comment: In general it is a very bad idea to think on formal logic using examples of the natural languages. This is the reason that approximately the 99% of introductory books to logic are terrible bad.

Comment: I disagree with that.  But you need to be logical in you language.  You must know and *think* A or -B means A, -B or possibly both is completely different than -A or B which means -A, B or possible both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I don't read or I pass".  means 1) It's possible that I don't read AND I pass and 2) It's impossible that I read AND fail. iii) Everything else is possible as either I won't read or I pass.

"I don't pass or I read"  means 1) It's POSSIBLE that I read and fail 2) It's IMPOSSIBLE that I don't read AND I pass. iii) Everything else is possible as either I won't pass or I will read.

You are thinking of the *exclusive* OR where Either A or B *but not both*.  In that case "either I don't read or I pass but not both" (So I better  read!) and "either I don't pass or I read but not both" (So I better  read!) are the same.

But with the normal OR, where Either A or B or both can happen they arent' the same because the "both" are contradictory.

"I don't pass or I read"  (Then I better read because i might pass but if I don't I WILL fail) is not the same as "I don't read or I pass" (Then I better read because I might pass if I don't but I WILL pass if I do) are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your question basically is:

Why is $\neg p \lor q$ not the same as $p \lor \neg q$?

OK, take:

p: $1+1=3$

q: $1+1=2$

Then: $\neg p \lor q$ i:s '$1+1\not=3$ or $1+1=2$' .. which is true

But: $p \lor \neg q$ is: '$1+1=3$ or $1+1 \not = 2$' .. which is false